# Why are the constraints not working when I add them programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have a view like this:

[image]

When I do a specific action, i want to show a view. These are my constraints:

```
    self.view.addSubview(messageView)
    let leftConstraint = messageView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.myTableView.leftAnchor)
    let bottomConstraint = messageView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.myTableView.bottomAnchor)
    let highConstratin = messageView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(44.0)
    let widthConstraint = messageView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.myTableView.widthAnchor)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([leftConstraint, bottomConstraint, highConstratin, widthConstraint])
    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
```

but the problem is that the view is just being added at the top left, like the constraints are not working,

see please

[image]

What did I miss please?

Comment: What if you do `messageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` before adding it as a subView?

Comment: You should tell more details in your question about what you want to do. You add a label in `self.view` and expect it to show on top of the table view at the bottom-left corner? and anything else? I have been using auto layout with tableview a lot and everything works fine. You don't need to worry about auto layout not working, you should worry about how you do it. So you have to provide more details about how you do it.

Comment: @vacawama then i receiving a warning about `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`

Comment: @JoeHuang please look again to the question, my label is in my messageView. i expect it to be at the bottom because i added the constraint to the bottom (if you don't knwo this, it's okay bty ) :)

Comment: you shouldn't do `self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` unless you are managing the self's view by yourself.

Comment: @chuthan20 so please what do you suggest ?

Comment: My *guess* would be that your self.view is a subclass of `UIScrollView`? (if your controller is subclass of `UITableViewController` then it's view is a `UITableView` which is a subclass of `UIScrollView`). If so, then people do have trouble with correctly using auto layout with `UIScrollView`. Maybe try wrapping the `messageView` into `UIView` which has the same width/height/origin as the `UITableView`. The problem might be that it might try to scroll with the `UITableView`. TBH, I don't know how to do this using auto layout, I would probably fallback to using `.frame` manipulation.

Comment: @chuthan20 my messageView is already a UIView. Okay if you don't know, then I'll wait for another user. thanks

Comment: I meant if your `self.view` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` then adding constraints might be complicated.

Comment: @chuthan20 i'm on UITableViewController, so my self.view is problem a subclass from scrollview

Comment: Yea sorry, I don't think I can help you. Also, If you could edit the question and add a few sentence about what do you want the constraints to do then people might be able to help you bit better? Maybe another picture of what you expect to happen? I am saying this because if you want to display something at the very end of the UITableView, then you can use `tableFooterView` on `UITableView`. People might be able to give you other suggestions if they know what you are trying to accomplish.